# Most efficient way to get last insert

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Which of these two methods is more efficient to retrieve account_balance from a large accounts table?

```
SELECT account_balance FROM accounts 
    WHERE account_no ='12345' 
    AND transaction_date =(SELECT MAX(transaction_date) FROM accounts);


SELECT account_balance FROM accounts 
    WHERE account_no ='12345'
    ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or if there is a better way than these two, I'd like to know.

Edit: the transaction_date is actually a timestamp. Not sure if it was obvious to you guys at first.

Comment: Your first query does not return desired result - it must have `WHERE account_no ='12345' ` in subquery.

Comment: The suspect the latter is more efficient, although I have no concrete evidence for it

Comment: I agree with Asad. Also if you index transaction_date this should be very quick.

Comment: @a1ex07, Both queries work fine with the same result. I tested before posting. :-)

Comment: @okeyxyz : The first one may give correct result only if the latest transaction belongs to account 12345. Otherwise, it will return empty resultset.

Comment: @a1ex07, I thought the first query does enough to make MAX(transaction_date) -this is actually timestamp- exclusive to account 12345. No?

Comment: Once you decide which method is fastest (I would bet on the latter) you MAY be able to get additional minor performance enhancement IF you are using an auto-increment key on the accounts table.  Use that instead of the transaction_date.

Comment: Have you consider using an **Having** clause?

Comment: `MAX(transaction_date)` returns the latest transaction date regardless of other values fields. It's quite possible that the latest transaction was made for other account (say for account 12345 transaction was made at 6PM, but for account 34567 at 8PM, MAX with no other filters returns 8PM). Then there is no record in `account` table where account = 12345  and transaction_date = 8PM

Comment: @a1ex07, I finally see what you were trying to say. You're right, the first query's faulty

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how critical the information that you are retrieving is, you may also want to use a table lock. This will ensure that no other transactions occur while the latest row is fetched.

In terms of efficiency, I would choose the former query (with `account_no` in the subquery and assuming that `transaction_date` is unique), as the latter will most likely require a file sort (unless you have an index on `transaction_date` that is ordered `DESC`).

Comment: Yeah, I thought the first query would be more efficient too(but i'm still learning) because of the latter producing a result set that would still need to be sorted after. especially if it's a large set.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should run `EXPLAIN` on your query to find out how MySQL "attacks" the problem.

Assuming that `transaction_date` is indexed (in descending order), the latter option is faster because it avoids an (independent) subquery on the same table. Otherwise, the former is faster, provided you move the account_no condition into the sub query.